# How to bundle node js and express js for production?

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on a project which run node express server and using Angular as frontend. I have build Angular project and placed files in public folder for node folder. I want to bundle express and node code for production where node code cannot be modified and easily understand. Can some one help me how can i bundle the node server?

Comment: There's no point to doing that. The server side-code is not downloaded to the browser, so you don't need to minify it. All you are doing is adding extra processing overhead. If someone gains access to your server to obtain your server-side code, at that point you are pretty much done for.

Comment: So how to you ship your code to production? Zip the code and send it to production server where node is running and start node express js?